# Securing all APIs in Azure API Management with AD

Tags: azure, owin, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

Is it possible to secure all APIs with one "shared" Azure Active Directory at the Azure Management Api level with following scenario:

1. User calls Azure API Management service pointing to Service X
2. If request is not authenticated user should provide Active Directory Creditentials
3. AD Creditentials are validated on separate component and token is returned
4. User use token to authenticate to Azure API Management service
5. If user is authenticated API Management Service use Basic Authentication to call Service X
6. One token can be used to access every Service, because it is validated in separate component.
7. Services are protected only with basic authentication which is configured in API Management Portal.
   [image]

Is this scenario possible to be implemented? If not how can I achieve something similiar with available components?

Answer (score 3):

Most of it should be possible using the API management policies.

2,3) use advanced policy features for this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn894085.aspx

4) add the `Validate JWT` policy:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/034febe3-465f-4840-9fc6-c448ef520b0f#ValidateJWT

```
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
    <openid-config url="https://login.windows.net/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    <required-claims>
        <claim name="id" match="all">
            <value>insert claim here</value>
        </claim>
    </required-claims>
</validate-jwt>
```

5) default behaviour, basic auth or certificate are the only options in azure api management (or pass the JWT), this can be set from the Azure portal as well.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn894079.aspx#Basic

7) yes, and the credentials can be stored secure in the new "properties" section of API management:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-properties/

Comment: Hi @Erik can you just explain what those `<claim name="id" match="all">
            <value>insert claim here</value>
        </claim>`
means? 
what is claim name? and what will be the value?

Comment: Hi @SohelReza, if you have a custom claim called (for example) "employeeType" and the current user has this claim, and a value of "Permanent Employee", the following will work:  

<claim name="EmployeeType" match="all">
            <value>Permanent Employee</value>
        </claim>

Now only users with this claim have access

Comment: Thanks @Erik for you reply. I you don't mind can you please help he at this point?
I am trying to validate my Bearer token that i generate from Azure AD  , at this point what will be my claim and value? 
I follow this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad
but at the end validate-jwt part i am getting confused i also enter my Application ID as it says in value section but its always rise error that written "Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid."